# MySQL on Ubuntu. 10061 error on 3306

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, iptables, firewall, virtualbox

A fresh install of Ubuntu inside of a Virtualbox with LAMP option selected. I am unable to connect to the server via telnet on this port or via ODBC from my host machine. I can ping and SSH both remotely and locally.

To start I tried flushing iptables`iptables -F`

I then tried disable afw`afw disable`

I then checked mysql's user table. host = %, user = user1  - checks out

`sudo netstat -pnlt | grep ':3306'` reveals this:

```
    tcp    0    0  127.0.0.1:3306    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    1329/mysqld
```

`nmap -sT -O localhost` tells me mysql is open and running on 3306 as well.

The virtual machine is set to run in Bridged Adapter mode.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Looks like your process is only listening on the loopback interface. You should also listen for external connections. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43025/how-to-allow-mysql-remote-connections-via-particular-interface for more information...